# Shoal water or Shallow water?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

Is there a difference between "**shoal water**" and "**shallow water**"?

I also heard a term "**low water**". Does it carry an equal meaning or is it closer to "**low tide**"?

Comment: "shoal" is used by itself, and can mean an area of shallow water. So use "shoal" or "shallow water". The meaning of "tide" is more complex, referring to a *relative* water height. More context would be needed to make any comparison.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks. I meant to say, is "**low water**" a synonym of "**shallow water**"?

Comment: *low water* is much more vague, and doesn't automatically infer the water depth. It could be lower than expected, but not shallow. Comparison is difficult without context.

Comment: Shoals are characteristically long and narrow (linear) ridges. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoal Where there are shoals, the water in and around them is generally shallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shoal water*, which is not a common expression<sup>1</sup> but can be understood simply as *shoal* being an attributive noun modifying *water*, means the water in or around a *shoal*, an area within a body of water that is shallower than the surrounding area (usually long and thin in shape). It is not necessary shallow in any absolute sense, but generally it is shallow enough to cause problems to the sort of shipping that is found in the wider body of water.

*Shallow water* means water that is, well, shallow. It might be meant in a relative sense, or an absolute sense, and it is a common term.

*Low water* is an expression used about any body of water that has a variable water level. This might be a river that is at different levels at different times of year due to different weather, or indeed a lake with the same variation. It can also be water that is tidal, either the sea or a tidal river. It refers to the lowest level that body of water tends to get to. The highest that body tends to get to is *high water*. *High water mark* is the visible indication, either natural or man-made, of the high water level at a certain point. It is also used metaphorically.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I've found some indications that it may have been part of a longer saying historically - "sailing in shoal water" - an expression that is still used now for literally sailing in the vicinity of shoals, but may have been a more general metaphor in the past.